# (More efficiently) solving for residue classes $\pmod {2^A}$?

Tags: diophantine-equations, recreational-mathematics, collatz-conjecture

This is in context to a detail for the generalized Collatz-problem (generalized to various multipliers, like *3x+1*, *5x+1*, *7x+1*, ... ,*mx+1*, ...)
I am currently looking at the *11x+1* problem , and as a basic feature for all that generalizations there occurs a table of residue classes, which also implies a systematic splitting of the integers in residue classes $\pmod{ 2^A}$ .

For instance, I'm looking at (odd) values *a* transformed to *b* 
 $$ a \to b:\qquad b=(11a+1)/2^A $$ 
where $A$ is that exponent which removes all primefactors 2 from *b* such that *b* is again odd.
Looking at a table of residue classes of $a \pmod {2\cdot 2^A}$ and $b \pmod {22}$ I get this (valid for any integer *k*)
$$\begin{array} {rr|rr}
 a   &  &   b \\ \hline
3&+2\cdot 2^1 k   & 17    &+2\cdot 11k   \\
1&+2\cdot 2^2 k    & 3    &+2\cdot 11k   \\
5&+2\cdot 2^3 k  &  7     &+2\cdot 11k  \\
13&+2\cdot 2^4 k  & 9     &+2\cdot 11k  \\
61&+2\cdot 2^5 k  & 21    &+2\cdot 11k   \\
29&+2\cdot 2^6 k & 5      &+2\cdot 11k \\
221&+2\cdot 2^7 k & 19    &+2\cdot 11k  \\
349&+2\cdot 2^8 k & 15    &+2\cdot 11k  \\
605&+2\cdot 2^9 k & 13    &+2\cdot 11k \\
93& +2\cdot 2^{10} k & 1  &+2\cdot 11k    \\ \hline
3165&+2\cdot 2^{11} k & 17 &+2\cdot 11k\\
 \cdots  & \cdots \\
\end{array}
$$
where for the residue classes *b* the table becomes periodic.
I know also, that the residues of *a* can be expressed by exploiting that *b*-periodicity, in that for instance $3165 = (3\cdot 2^{10} + 93) $ and the next entry for *a* is $ (1\cdot 2^{10} + 93) + 2\cdot 2^{12}k$

Well, all this works very nice, but now I'm fiddling with the problem to *efficiently* find the proper residue class if I have some given odd *a* .
Of course I could search by brute force working through all residue classes. ("brute force" means here, when I take instead the multiplier *m=11* a much larger multiplier to solve the same problem).

> But is there a more elegant way to do this, say given $a=6237$ to find easily which residue class this is in?

---

***[update]***
What I have tried so far, next to "brute force", is to install translation tables from/for the residue classes. So when I have an unknown *a* I compute *b* determine the residueclass $r_b=\pmod{2\cdot 11}$ look in the indextable for $r_b$ to get the class index $i$ and get from the residuetable for $r_a$ at index $i$ the decomposition.

```
resclass_a=[3,1,5,13,61,29,221,349,605,93]        
resclass_b=[17,3,7,9,21,5,18,15,13,1]
    classindex_b=vector(22);for(k=1,10,i=resclass_b [k];classindex_b[i]=k);
\\ Pari/GP commands        \\ --- Pari/GP-output

k= 3                   \\ construct some test number
93 + 2*2^10*k          \\   %576 = 6237

                           \\ ----------------run test
a = 6237                   \\   %579 = 6237
b = it(a)                  \\   %580 = 67
i = classindex_b[b % 22]   \\   %581 = 10

r_a=resclass_a[i ]         \\   %582 = 93
k = (a-ra ) /(2*2^i)       \\   %583 = 3
```

So I detected the correct decomposition.

Even I found, that the sequence $[17,3,7,...]$ coincides with $[17,17^2,17^3,...] \pmod{22}$ but I've no idea how to derive something more efficients than before.
But still, could I write this by some more smooth formula, possibly including things like reciprocal residues like $1/a \pmod {2^k} $ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, ***the  trivial method*** is the best/only one/... .
The exponent $A$, found by doing the iteration on some odd inital $a$ :
 $$A = \{m\cdot a+1,2\}$$ 
$\qquad \qquad $ where the curly-braces indicate extraction of the exponent of one primefactor (here:$2$), then 
$$ b= (m\cdot a + 1)/2^A $$ 
$\qquad \qquad $ $\qquad \qquad $taken as just the index does the job, I think in the most simple way thinkable.

***Example***
So let $m=11$ and for instance $a=6237 $ as indicated in the question. Then $$A = \{11 \cdot 6237+1,2\} = 10$$ 
and of course $A=10$ points to the residue class $r_{a,10}=93$. Then
 $$ \begin{eqnarray}a&=& 93+ 2\cdot 2^{10}\cdot k \\
   k &=& (a-93)/2^{11} &=& 3 \\
  a&= &93+ 3 \cdot 2^{11} \\
 b&=& 1 + 3 \cdot 22 &=& 67
 \end{eqnarray}$$
I could not find a shorter/more efficient way ...